How does the next PAGE hardware prefetcher work?
L2/L3 hardware prefetcher behaviors are well documented (their aggressiveness, their tiggers, etc). However, very little is known about the next-page prefetcher that supposedly pre-loads the TLB when access patterns are sequential. Other than this Intel forum discussion, I have not been able to find anything of significance. Not even in the Intel Software Development Manual. I am interested in knowing the following about the prefetcher:

How do I check if this feature is available on my processor?
How is it triggered? Accesses to first cache line of contiguous pages in virtual address space (the above discussion says page prefetches made when virtual address are accessed sequentially)
How aggressive is the prefetching? That is how many pages are prefetched ahead of current page access? Does this depend on the page granularity set (4 KiB, 2 MiB, etc)?

The Intel Optimization Reference Manual [4.1.7 Cache and Memory Subsystem] sheds a little light on this:

There are three independent L1 prefetchers. One does a simple next-line fetch on DL1 load misses. The second is an instruction pointer based prefetcher capable of detecting striding access patterns of various sizes. This prefetcher works in the linear address space so it is capable of crossing page boundaries and starting translations for TLB misses. The final prefetcher is a next-page prefetcher that detects accesses that are likely to cross a page boundary and starts the access early. L1 data misses generated by these prefetchers communicate additional information to the L2 prefetchers, which help them work together.

TIL L1 prefetchers can cross page boundaries and can trigger page walks on TLB miss! For Gracemount microarchitecture (Intel Atom). Why a low-voltage/low-performance processor would require such aggressive power hungry hardware units is a question on its own.
